# Encoding String to UTF-8 working with JSON in android

Tags: java, android, json, utf-8

I have a problem with converting a `String` to UTF-8.

I have tried these approaches to converting, but the result is not correct:

1. `String fname = new String(_fnameText.getText().toString().getBytes(UTF8));`
2. `String fname = URLEncoder.encode(_fnameText.getText().toString(),"UTF8");`

The result for the first one is like : `?????? ??????`

The result for the second one is like : `%30%D%40.....`

How can I convert a `String` to UTF-8 ?

This is my code :

```
public void signup() {
    String name;
    String fname;
    String lname;
    String password;
    final Charset UTF8=Charset.forName("utf-8");
    name = new String();
    fname = new String(_fnameText.getText().toString().getBytes(UTF8));
    lname = new String(_lnameText.getText().toString().getBytes(UTF8));
    password = new String(_passwordText.getText().toString().getBytes(UTF8));
    // TODO: Implement your own signup logic here.
    if(name!=null && fname!=null && lname!=null && password!=null) {
        if (isConnected()) {
            if (validate()) {
                _signupButton.setEnabled(false);
                jsonSignup = new JSON_Signup(SignupActivity.this, "http://teroject.com/api/android.php", name, password);
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "teroapi_php_java_1395"));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_function", "register"));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
                jsonSignup.execute();
            }
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"لطفا از کاراکتر های مجاز استفاده کنید",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public JSON_Signup(Context context,String url,String username,String password){
        this.context=context;
        this.url=url;
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("در حال ثبت نام لطفا صبر کنید....");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                JSON_Signup.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // Set up HTTP post
            // HttpClient is more then less deprecated. Need to change to URLConnection
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valuesForServer));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                // Read content & Log
                inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e7){
            Log.i("Network on Main Thread", e7 + "");
            e7.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e6){
            Log.i("Connection Timeout", e6 + "");
            e6.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            Log.i("Unsupported Encoding",e1+"");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
            Log.i("Client Protocol", e2 + "");
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
            Log.i("Illegal State", e3 + "");
            e3.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e4) {
            Log.i("Exception", e4 + "");
            e4.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        // Convert response to string using String Builder
        if(inputStream!=null) {
            try {
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }

                inputStream.close();
                result = sBuilder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Exception", e + "");
                return null;
            }
        }else {
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            //parse JSON data
            try {
                mainFile = new JSONObject(result);
                success = mainFile.getString("success");
                message = mainFile.getString("message");
                if (success.equals("1")) {
                    _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
                    Toast.makeText(this.context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (isConnected()) {
                        JSON json;
                        json = new JSON(this.context, "http://teroject.com/api/android.php",
                                this.username,this.password);
                        json.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "teroapi_php_java_1395"));
                        json.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_function", "login"));
                        json.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",this.username));
                        json.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",this.password));
                        json.execute();
                    }
                } else if (success.equals("0")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this.context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this.context, e + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }else {
            _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(this.context,"خطا در برقراری ارتباط",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Log :

```
08-02 01:22:59.185 1108-1159/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
08-02 01:22:59.445 15868-15868/? E/chromium: [ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2218)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
08-02 01:23:00.349 271-822/? E/BandwidthController: [LG DATA] No such appUid: 10044
08-02 01:23:00.767 275-1078/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:00.767 275-1078/? E/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: enter  2
08-02 01:23:01.683 30716-30716/? E/MusicBrowser: [MusicUtils.java:633:getSmartShareVersion()] oooooo getSmartShareVersion ERROR :: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.lge.smartshare
08-02 01:23:02.445 32207-32207/? E/LGDMClient: [DmNotiService.java] [onCreate()] : [153] : DmNotiService.onCreate()
08-02 01:23:03.971 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: enter 2
08-02 01:23:13.001 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
08-02 01:23:13.001 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
08-02 01:23:13.042 32587-32616/com.teroject.teroject E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
08-02 01:23:13.724 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/MediaProfilesEx-JNI: register_com_lge_media_MediaProfilesEx
08-02 01:23:13.724 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/MediaRecorderEx-JNI: register_com_lge_media_MediaRecorderEx
08-02 01:23:13.726 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/SurfaceControlEx: register_com_lge_view_SurfaceControlEx
08-02 01:23:13.736 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/MediaPlayerEx-jni: register_com_lge_view_MediaPlayerEx
08-02 01:23:17.325 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
08-02 01:23:19.477 2636-2636/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
08-02 01:23:19.477 2636-2636/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
08-02 01:23:19.579 2032-4467/? E/Drive.UninstallOperation: Package still installed com.teroject.teroject
08-02 01:23:21.148 275-1078/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:21.148 275-1078/? E/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: enter  2
08-02 01:23:21.577 409-409/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bo.a(837): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
08-02 01:23:22.539 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:23.112 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:23.293 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:24.199 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:24.565 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:24.954 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:25.744 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:26.073 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:26.273 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:26.714 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:28.023 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:28.259 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:28.445 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:28.638 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:28.835 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:29.042 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:29.275 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:29.739 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:30.509 2032-905/? E/IntentOperationSvc: Failed to instantiate Chimera operation impl, dropping operation
08-02 01:23:30.583 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:30.658 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/View: hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls
08-02 01:23:32.265 914-914/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bo.a(837): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
08-02 01:23:32.958 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:33.229 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:33.823 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:34.129 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:34.336 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:34.387 2636-2636/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
08-02 01:23:34.387 2636-2636/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
08-02 01:23:34.662 1186-1186/? E/App: [App][onCreate()] 4.40.21
08-02 01:23:34.785 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:36.379 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:36.488 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/View: hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls
08-02 01:23:37.519 1310-1310/? E/LGDMClient: [DmNotiService.java] [onCreate()] : [153] : DmNotiService.onCreate()
08-02 01:23:37.600 271-822/? E/BandwidthController: [LG DATA] No such appUid: 10100
08-02 01:23:37.832 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:38.623 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:38.972 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:39.463 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:39.810 1310-1310/? E/LGDMClient: [DmNotiService.java] [onCreate()] : [153] : DmNotiService.onCreate()
08-02 01:23:40.283 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:40.548 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:40.749 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:41.392 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:42.272 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:42.368 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/View: hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls
08-02 01:23:42.509 1228-1228/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
08-02 01:23:42.537 1228-1267/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
08-02 01:23:42.642 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:42.922 271-822/? E/BandwidthController: [LG DATA] No such appUid: 10101
08-02 01:23:42.942 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:43.205 271-822/? E/BandwidthController: [LG DATA] No such appUid: 10101
08-02 01:23:43.435 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:44.025 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:44.285 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:44.495 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:45.733 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:46.999 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:23:47.101 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/View: hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls
08-02 01:23:47.967 1566-1566/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bo.a(837): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
08-02 01:23:48.401 271-822/? E/BandwidthController: [LG DATA] No such appUid: 10151
08-02 01:23:48.469 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
08-02 01:23:50.138 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: enter 2
08-02 01:23:54.695 1310-1310/? E/LGDMClient: [DmNotiService.java] [onCreate()] : [153] : DmNotiService.onCreate()
08-02 01:23:55.483 271-822/? E/BandwidthController: [LG DATA] No such appUid: 10151
08-02 01:24:00.979 1310-1310/? E/LGDMClient: [DmNotiService.java] [onCreate()] : [153] : DmNotiService.onCreate()
08-02 01:24:01.475 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/OneSignal: You must initialize OneSignal before modifying tags! Omitting this tag operation.
08-02 01:24:02.643 32587-32587/com.teroject.teroject E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
08-02 01:24:04.019 2636-1894/? E/CommitToConfigurationOperation: Malformed snapshot token (size): 
08-02 01:24:04.045 2636-1894/? E/CommitToConfigurationOperation: Malformed snapshot token (size): 
08-02 01:24:04.079 2636-1894/? E/CommitToConfigurationOperation: Malformed snapshot token (size): 
08-02 01:24:04.142 271-822/? E/BandwidthController: [LG DATA] No such appUid: 10004
08-02 01:24:04.408 275-1078/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:24:04.408 275-1078/? E/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: enter  2
08-02 01:24:05.356 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(1)
08-02 01:24:08.505 275-1324/? E/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: enter 2
08-02 01:24:10.637 271-822/? E/BandwidthController: [LG DATA] No such appUid: 10151
```

Comment: What is in that _fnameText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to convert a `String` to UTF-8 is to call `getBytes()` by itself:

```
byte[] fname = _fnameText.getText().toString().getBytes(UTF8);
```

You are doing that fine, but then you are doing other things with that output that are not fine.

Your first example is wrong because you are converting the UTF-8 bytes back to a `String` using Java's default charset, which is clearly not UTF-8 on your system.

Your second example is wrong because you are manually URL-encoding the UTF-8 bytes at the wrong stage of your HTTP logic.

You should not be converting your individual input strings to UTF-8 at all.  Build up your HTTP request values as needed, and then let `UrlEncodedFormEntity` handle the conversion to UTF-8 when posting over HTTP.  `UrlEncodedFormEntity()` has two constructors, one of which takes an `encoding` as an input parameter, but you are not using that constructor.

Try something more like this:

```
public void signup() {
    String name = new String();
    String fname = _fnameText.getText().toString();
    String lname = _lnameText.getText().toString();
    String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
    // TODO: Implement your own signup logic here.
    if(name!=null && fname!=null && lname!=null && password!=null) {
        if (isConnected()) {
            if (validate()) {
                _signupButton.setEnabled(false);
                jsonSignup = new JSON_Signup(SignupActivity.this, "http://teroject.com/api/android.php", name, password);
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "teroapi_php_java_1395"));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_function", "register"));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
                jsonSignup.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
                jsonSignup.execute();
            }
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "لطفا از کاراکتر های مجاز استفاده کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public JSON_Signup(Context context, String url, String username, String password){
        this.context=context;
        this.url=url;
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
        valuesForServer=new List<BasicNameValuePair>();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("در حال ثبت نام لطفا صبر کنید....");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                JSON_Signup.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // Set up HTTP post
            // HttpClient is more then less deprecated. Need to change to URLConnection
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valuesForServer, "utf-8"));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                // Read content & Log
                inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e7){
            Log.i("Network on Main Thread", e7 + "");
            e7.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e6){
            Log.i("Connection Timeout", e6 + "");
            e6.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            Log.i("Unsupported Encoding",e1+"");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
            Log.i("Client Protocol", e2 + "");
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
            Log.i("Illegal State", e3 + "");
            e3.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e4) {
            Log.i("Exception", e4 + "");
            e4.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        // Convert response to string using String Builder
        if(inputStream!=null) {
            try {
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }

                inputStream.close();
                result = sBuilder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Exception", e + "");
                return null;
            }
        }else {
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            //parse JSON data
            try {
                mainFile = new JSONObject(result);
                success = mainFile.getString("success");
                message = mainFile.getString("message");
                if (success.equals("1")) {
                    _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
                    Toast.makeText(this.context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (isConnected()) {
                        JSON json = new JSON(this.context, "http://teroject.com/api/android.php", this.username, this.password);
                        json.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "teroapi_php_java_1395"));
                        json.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_function", "login"));
                        json.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", this.username));
                        json.valuesForServer.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", this.password));
                        json.execute();
                    }
                } else if (success.equals("0")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this.context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this.context, e + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }else {
            _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(this.context,"خطا در برقراری ارتباط",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

You did not show the code for `JSON.execute()`, but the concept is the same.  Collect the HTTP values as normal `String` values, and then let `UrlEncodedFormEntity` convert the values to UTF-8 when posting the final HTTP request.